# Rails: groupdate GEM change group resolution dynamic on parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, group-by, resolution

Is there a way to use the groupdate gem with a dynamic parameter for data resolution?

Normally you can use

```
User.group_by_day(:created_at).count
```

or

```
User.group_by_week(:created_at).count
```

But I want to use the day/week option by parameter to change the charts. So I need something like

```
User.group_by_groupdate(:created_at, resolution: params[:resolution]).count
```

Where params[:resolution] can be "day", "week", "month", "year", instead of doing something like this:

```
case params[:resolution]
when "day"
User.group_by_day(:created_at).count
when "week"
User.group_by_week(:created_at).count
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [docs](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate), you can do this

```
User.group_by_period(params[:resolution], :created_at, permit: %w[day week month year]).count
```

In `permit` option you can pass available periods. When you pass something else, `ArgumentError` will be raised.

Comment: Thank you! .. did not see that!